# Is my prayer still valid?

Tags: salat, quran-recitation

I’m a non Arabic speaking muslim and sometimes I unintentionally mispronounce some words during salat. I have a hard time pronouncing the g in “ghayril” during Al-Fatiha and today I realized i mispronounced it so I tried my best to correct my mistake and continue on. I also feel like I mispronounced a word during tashahhud in the “al” in “ash hadu al la ilaha”, but I didn’t go back and correct this one. I did however ask that Allah forgives me for any mistakes in my prayer while making dua. Would my prayer still be valid?

Answer (score 1):

Our prophet pbuh said :
"Actions are (judged) by motives (niyyah), so each man will have what he intended. Thus, he whose migration (hijrah) was to Allah and His Messenger, his migration is to Allah and His Messenger; but he whose migration was for some worldly thing he might gain, or for a wife he might marry, his migration is to that for which he migrated." [Bukhari & Muslim]

Answer (score 1):

Alsalam alikum, dont worry brother/syster you'r prayer is accepted and mashallah from the ease of our deen the prophet [pbuh] said that if you strugel to read the quran you will get more rewards for doing it even if you say something wrong but the important thing is that you try to make it better.